# Visual Studio auto generated function only when class has pointer member

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I was playing around with [DIA SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx) today, trying to print all the functions in a .pdb file generated by VS(2012). In the output I noticed a function called **__autoclassinit**( with an unsigned int as a parameter ) was generated for one my test classes (the only with with a pointer member).

Google failed to return any results so I ask you: what does this function do? and why isn't it used for references too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First google hit for "__autoclassinit"

[blogs.msdn.com...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sdl/archive/2012/03/08/guarding-against-uninitialized-class-member-pointers.aspx)

> ...compiler will generate a new function called A::_*autoclassinit(). This function is responsible for the initialization of class member pointers. It will also call the compiler-generated class initialization functions of any base classes or member variable of a class type. For our example the A::*_autoclassinit() function is called before the call to the constructor:
>   ...